# Showing two Icons when launch application

Tags: android

I want some assistance on Icons showing for my application, there are two icons one for my Library Project FBReader and one for my own launcher app. I make all changes as suggested on different web portals and StackOverflow but didn't get success. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.handygo.rockasap"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="70"
    android:versionName="4.3.3" >

    <!-- android:maxSdkVersion="17" max version create problem in Reader -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
    <permission
        android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

   <!-- <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />-->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" >
    </uses-feature>
    <!-- Version check the WIFI and Location permission -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />

    **<application
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:name, android:theme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:name=".RockstandApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >**

        <!-- MOBIKWIK Activity Files -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.MobikwikSDK"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="MobiKwik"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTransparent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <!-- PayTM Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.PGWebView"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="BankPage"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.PaymentOptions"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.PaymentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.GetUserDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>


        <!-- multiwindow code -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.multiinstance.enable"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.STYLE"
            android:value="fixedRatio" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
            android:value="true" />

        <service android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.apputils.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.apputils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.handygo.rockasap" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.DataProvider"
            android:authorities="com.handygo.rockasap.DataProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true" >
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.FixBooksDirectoryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="CachedCharStorageException" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="ExceptionInInitializerError" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.api.ApiService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.API" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ScreenShotsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.SpeakActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.Panel" />
        **<activity
            tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:name, android:theme"
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
            android:label="Rockstand"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>**
        <activity android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.DictionaryBrowser" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.CancelActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.style.StyleListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.style.EditStyleActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.image.ImageViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <!-- android:process=":imageView" -->
        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.libraryService.LibraryService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":libraryService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.LIBRARY_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.BookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.LibrarySearchActivity"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.LibraryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.LibrarySearchActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.TOCActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.BookmarksActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.BookmarkEditActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.preferences.PreferenceActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.preferences.EditBookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BookDownloader"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BookDownloaderService"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":networkLibrary" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkSearchActivity"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkLibraryPrimaryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkLibrarySecondaryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AuthenticationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BuyBooksActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AddCatalogMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AddCustomCatalogActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AuthorizationMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.TopupMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkBookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.ListenerCallback"
            android:process=":networkLibrary" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.network.SIGNIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <!--
             <activity
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.screens.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        -->

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RockstandFragmentScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_filters"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"></activity>




        <!-- The authenticator service -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.ReferralReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
 </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.AuthenticationService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <!--<receiver
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.UpdatePaymentSuccess">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="update_paytm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You have multiple.  `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` intents

Comment: There are MultiWindow launcher attached which is different from Launcher. Even Laucher icons not showing of the same Activity, it is showing of FBReader Activity. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you put two intent filters,remove one

```
<activity
        android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.FixBooksDirectoryActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:process=":crash"
        android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="CachedCharStorageException" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:process=":crash"
        android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="ExceptionInInitializerError" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have 2 LAUNCHER activities in your manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The 2 line

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
```

are both launchers. Remove 1

Comment: No, Please see my comment on #cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, either remove the intentfilters or set the category of either to `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`

Note that if you dont declare it to `DEFAULT`, the compiler does it for you automatically.

Comment: No, Please see my comment on #cricket_007